# Cross browser compatibility with SVG background

Tags: svg

I work on a app which supports on IE 10 and Chrome. For background images we go with svg sprite.Wherever we need to position icons we have defined a common class for the image and also defined class based on the icon.

Once we build the app, we found the positioning is fine on chrome browser and for IE we need to write a separate css fix based on the browser.
html

```
<ul>
<li><a class="pico menu href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

My css looks like

```
.pico:after{
  background:('sprite.svg') 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: 280px 660px;
  position:absolute;
  content:""
}


.pico.menu:after{
  background-position:-106px 6px;
}

.ie .pico.menu:after{
   background-position:-110px 6px;
}
```

Is there anyway to have a generic styles for IE and Chrome ?. Or is the default behavior of the browsers.

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="300px" height="650px" viewBox="561 165 246 580" enable-background="new 561 165 246 580" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <g>
        <polygon fill="#F47621" points="580.3,230 585.5,235.2 590.8,230 589.8,229 585.5,233.1 581.3,229         "/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <polygon fill="#F47621" points="580.3,225.5 585.5,230.7 590.8,225.5 589.8,224.6 585.5,228.8 581.3,224.6         "/>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: What exactly happens on IE?  Perhaps you could make a code snippet or add an image.  Also, the contents of sprite.svg may be important.  Can you link it, or at least show us the first `<svg>` tag, with attributes.

Comment: attached the sample svg @PaulLeBeau

Comment: A working example would be useful. Without the HTML and the rest of the CSS for ".pico" we can't really tell what is going wrong.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pae7bv3x/

Comment: @PaulLeBeau svg image embedded in data-uri

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pae7bv3x/1/

Comment: Needing to find a workaround for IE is  normal and expected for many things.

Comment: @Rob writing a separate styles for ie is normal right. It wont have any performance issue. Since i need to write 40-60 lines of code for IE browser for the anchor tag active and hover position

Answer (score 0):

Here i cleaned up some of the code. Don't use the external url for your images of course.

Tested in chrome and IE 11 and IE 10. Both will display the image correctly.

```css
.pico::after {
  background: url(http://imgh.us/test_55.svg) 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: 280px 660px;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
}
.pico.menu::after {
  background-position: -10px -65px;
}
svg {
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="pico menu" href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="300px" height="650px" viewBox="561 165 246 580" enable-background="new 561 165 246 580" xml:space="preserve">
  <polygon fill="#F47621" points="580.3,230 585.5,235.2 590.8,230 589.8,229 585.5,233.1 581.3,229         " />
  <polygon fill="#F47621" points="580.3,225.5 585.5,230.7 590.8,225.5 589.8,224.6 585.5,228.8 581.3,224.6         " />
</svg>
```